# Discrepancy in memory usage as reported by R and that reported by Linux OS

Tags: r, centos

I have a CSV file of size around 5.9GB on the disk. I read this file in R and measure its size. I find its size in R of around 7.7 GB. But I find OS has occupied around 22GB of additional space after file reading. This large discrepancy in memory occupation is unclear.

Here are the details. I read the file in R with the command:

```
    data<-read.csv("train.csv",header=TRUE, colClasses=c('character','factor','numeric',rep('factor',21)))
```

The file has 24 features. One character, one numeric and all other factors. On reading the file, I check up in R the size of 'data' object. I get the size of around 7.7 GB as can be seen below:

```
    > library(pryr)
    > object_size(data)
    7.72 GB
    > object.size(data)
    7720196888 bytes
    > ls()
    [1] "data"
```

But, my operating system reports a huge additional consumption of memory. Difference between before and after reading of csv file is around 22Gb which is much more than the reported 7.7GB by R. My before and after memory consumptions are as below. Please see below that both RAM (*MemTotal* and *MemFree*) and SWAP (*SwapTotal* and *SwapFree*) are almost totally unused:

```
    Before reading CSV file:

    [xyz@master ~]$ cat /proc/meminfo 
    MemTotal:       16169156 kB
    MemFree:        14437468 kB
    Buffers:           47676 kB
    Cached:           492140 kB
    SwapCached:            0 kB
    Active:          1036052 kB
    Inactive:         439512 kB
    Active(anon):     936628 kB
    Inactive(anon):   135584 kB
    Active(file):      99424 kB
    Inactive(file):   303928 kB
    Unevictable:           0 kB
    Mlocked:               0 kB
    SwapTotal:      28631036 kB
    SwapFree:       28631036 kB
    Dirty:               100 kB
    Writeback:             0 kB
    AnonPages:        937792 kB
    Mapped:           184784 kB
    Shmem:            136468 kB
    Slab:              75220 kB
    SReclaimable:      39404 kB
    SUnreclaim:        35816 kB
    KernelStack:        3040 kB
    PageTables:        31976 kB
    NFS_Unstable:          0 kB
    Bounce:                0 kB
    WritebackTmp:          0 kB
    CommitLimit:    36715612 kB
    Committed_AS:    5681212 kB
    VmallocTotal:   34359738367 kB
    VmallocUsed:      386168 kB
    VmallocChunk:   34359345404 kB
    HardwareCorrupted:     0 kB
    AnonHugePages:    749568 kB
    HugePages_Total:       0
    HugePages_Free:        0
    HugePages_Rsvd:        0
    HugePages_Surp:        0
    Hugepagesize:       2048 kB
    DirectMap4k:        8192 kB
    DirectMap2M:    16611328 kB
```

After reading the 5.9GB csv file in R, the memory consumption is as below. RAM is almost fully used (additional used up around 13GB) and 9GB of SWAP is also used up.

```
    After reading CSV file:       

    [xyz@master ~]$ cat /proc/meminfo 
    MemTotal:       16169156 kB
    MemFree:          945528 kB
    Buffers:           17996 kB
    Cached:           243140 kB
    SwapCached:      5924192 kB
    Active:         12021068 kB
    Inactive:        2918636 kB
    Active(anon):   11969848 kB
    Inactive(anon):  2758740 kB
    Active(file):      51220 kB
    Inactive(file):   159896 kB
    Unevictable:           0 kB
    Mlocked:               0 kB
    SwapTotal:      28631036 kB
    SwapFree:       18888240 kB
    Dirty:                68 kB
    Writeback:             0 kB
    AnonPages:      13982076 kB
    Mapped:            58652 kB
    Shmem:             50020 kB
    Slab:              69332 kB
    SReclaimable:      32176 kB
    SUnreclaim:        37156 kB
    KernelStack:        3304 kB
    PageTables:        68284 kB
    NFS_Unstable:          0 kB
    Bounce:                0 kB
    WritebackTmp:          0 kB
    CommitLimit:    36715612 kB
    Committed_AS:   23674336 kB
    VmallocTotal:   34359738367 kB
    VmallocUsed:      386168 kB
    VmallocChunk:   34359345404 kB
    HardwareCorrupted:     0 kB
    AnonHugePages:   4655104 kB
    HugePages_Total:       0
    HugePages_Free:        0
    HugePages_Rsvd:        0
    HugePages_Surp:        0
    Hugepagesize:       2048 kB
    DirectMap4k:        8192 kB
    DirectMap2M:    16611328 kB
```

Such large discrepancy in memory usage, i.e. one reported by R and the other reported by OS (I have CentOS) is not understood.

I Will be grateful for explanation.

Comment: You may find [this link](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/memory.html#gc) useful.

Comment: I did saw this link. It has functions to calculate internal memory usage (that is memory usage of objects from within R). But it is not clear why OS is showing a huge memory occupancy. R Command mem_used() reports 8.8 GB. Thanks.